# two window objects in extjs

Tags: extjs

I have these two windows defined as shown below. The functionality that I desire is that initially the grid window should be hidden and the login window should be shown. After the user logs in, the login window should be hidden and the grid window should be shown.

```
var store = new Ext.data.Store({
    url: 'sheldon.xml',
    reader: new Ext.data.XmlReader({
        record: 'Item',
        fields: [
            {name: 'Title'},
            {name: 'Author'},
            {name: 'Manufacturer'},
            {name: 'ProductGroup'}
        ]
    })
});
LoginWindow = {};
gridWindow = {};
gridWindow.grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    store: store,
    columns: [
        {header: "Title", width: 120, dataIndex: 'Title', sortable:true},
        {header: "Author", width: 180, dataIndex: 'Author', sortable: true},
    ],
    height:200,
    viewConfig: {
        forceFit:true
    }
});

gridWindow = {
    xtype: 'window',
    id: 'grid',
    title: 'Grid',
    anchor: '30% 25%',
    items:[gridWindow.grid],
    frame:true,
    layout:'card',
};
LoginWindow.loginForm = {
    xtype:'form',
    // url:'check.php',
    frame: true,
    labelAlign:'right',
    labelWidth: 70,
    items:[
        {
            xtype:'textfield',
            fieldLabel:'Username',
            anchor: '100%'
        },
        {
            xtype:'textfield',
            fieldLabel:'Password',
            inputType:'password',
            anchor: '100%',
        }
    ],
    buttons:[
        {
            text:'Login',
            handler:
                // Dummy function
                function(btn, objc) {
                    Ext.getCmp('loginwindow').hide();
                    Ext.getCmp('grid').show();
                    store.load();
                },
        },
        {
            text:'Cancel',
            handler:function(btn, objc) {
                btn.findParentByType('form').getForm().reset();
            }
        }
    ]
};
LoginWindow = {
    xtype: 'window',
    id: 'loginwindow',
    title: 'Please Log In',
    anchor: '30% 25%',
    activeItem: 0,
    items:[LoginWindow.loginForm],
    frame:true,
    layout:'card',
    bodyStyle:{}
};
Ext.onReady(function() {
    var viewport = new Ext.Viewport({
        layout: 'anchor',
        items:[
            LoginWindow
        ]
    });
    Ext.getCmp('loginwindow').show();
    Ext.getCmp('grid').hide();
});
```

When I load the page, I get the error `Ext.getcmp('grid')` is undefined in firefox.
Could someone please help me out here...

Comment: And `Ext.getcmp` in the last line of your post has a typo and should be `Ext.getCmp`. Your code snippet seems OK (in regards to `Ext.getCmp`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `gridWindow` only exists as an object literal (aka xtype config object) and is never 'instantiated' (created). Therefore `Ext.getCmp` cannot find it, because it doesn't 'exist' yet and hasn't been registered with `Ext.ComponentManager`.

You could add it to the Viewport and add `hidden:true` to its config definition so it doesn't show up.

```
gridWindow = {
    xtype: 'window',
    id: 'grid',
    title: 'Grid',
    anchor: '30% 25%',
    items:[gridWindow.grid],
    frame:true,
    layout:'card',
};

Ext.onReady(function() {
    var viewport = new Ext.Viewport({
        layout: 'anchor',
        items:[
            LoginWindow, gridWindow
        ]
    });
    // no need
    //Ext.getCmp('loginwindow').show();
    //Ext.getCmp('grid').hide();
});
```

Note: you might also need to call doLayout() on your viewport in your login handler after showing/hiding the components.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you first define LoginWindow.loginForm, but then redefine LoginWindow with a new object.

```
LoginWindow.loginForm = {
    xtype:'form',
    // url:'check.php',
```

`LoginWindow` is now set to an object literal with one property `loginForm`.

```
{
    loginForm: [object]    
}
```

Followed by

```
LoginWindow = {
    xtype: 'window',
    id: 'loginwindow',
```

This will create a completely new object and assign it to `LoginWindow`. The `loginForm` property is nowhere to be seen anymore ;)

Comment: But the login window is rendered as expected. I'm getting error for `Ext.getCmp('grid')`.

Comment: oh, I see now. The `LoginWindow =` statement is evaluated from right to left. Assigning the LoginForm as item and only then the LoginWindow variable reference is overwritten. Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: I dont know why only 'loginwindow' is rendered and not 'grid' window too. I checked the dom and I can see only 'loginwindow'

Comment: I just posted a new answer. I will not delete this one, though, because I think it can be of some help to you. Personally, I recommend to change your coding style in regards to my observation. You might run into problems later because of it.